# how to crawl a nextpage of a website when it doesn't show the maximum page

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

here is the website(http://biz.chosun.com/svc/list_in/list.html?catid=1A&pn=1) I am trying to crawl, my question is how to go next page after crawling the first page. In this website page source, it doesn't show the maximum page, but I found that it can go up to 7000.

here is the code I tried but failed.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is keep a check on the current url. When you click on next button the url changes.

URL of page 1 - http://biz.chosun.com/svc/list_in/list.html?catid=1A&pn=0

URL of page 2 - http://biz.chosun.com/svc/list_in/list.html?catid=1A&pn=2

Suppose you are on last page and you try to click on the next button, it will give you the same URL.

So, you should code something like:

```
String current_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String previous_URL = null;
while (current_URL != previous_URL)
{
   // perform operations;
   previous_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl(); 
   // click on next;
   current_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feed back so I assuming u want me to do something like                        String current_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String previous_URL = null;
while (current_URL != previous_URL)
{
   gotourl(oldurl)
   // perform operations;
   previous_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl(); 
   // click on next;
   gotourl(nexturl)
   current_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
}

Comment: hello in fact do you know how to fix the provblem when I type While (current url ! = previous url ) it says I can't automatically convert string to bool...

Comment: you can use 
while(!current_url.equals("previous_url"))